# Overriding getOffsetParent() function in prototype.js in a separate file

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs, mixins

I am trying to apply a patch to prototype.js to fix layout issues in IE8 to IE10. I need to apply this patch in a separate file because prototype.js is one of the core files in our cms. I tried a lot of ways but all of the patch I tried are mostly ignored and the function in the original file is still being used. Below is the code that is the closest I can get it to work. The function below is executing instead of the original, however, the functions inside it are not working causing the script to not work. Any advice? I'm trying to apply the patch in https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/issues/156 in a separate file. My file prototype-patch.js is loaded after prototype.js.

```
Element.getOffsetParent = Element.getOffsetParent.wrap(function (element) {
element = $(element);
alert(element);
if (isDocument(element) || isDetached(element) || isBody(element) || isHtml(element))
    return $(document.body);
alert('test2');
var isInline = (Element.getStyle(element, 'display') === 'inline');
if (!isInline && element.offsetParent && Element.visible(element)) return $(element.offsetParent);
while ((element = element.parentNode) && element !== document.body) {
    if (Element.getStyle(element, 'position') !== 'static') {
        return isHtml(element) ? $(document.body) : $(element);
    }
}
return $(document.body);
});

Element.addMethods({
    getOffsetParent: Element.getOffsetParent
});
```

Comment: which version are you using in your CMS? 1.7.2 has this patch in it.

Comment: I'm using 1.7 which doesn't have the patch yet. Your answer helped me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the method this way

```
var getOffsetParent = function (element) {
    element = $(element);
    if (isDocument(element) || isDetached(element) || isBody(element) || isHtml(element))
        return $(document.body);
    var isInline = (Element.getStyle(element, 'display') === 'inline');
    if (!isInline && element.offsetParent && Element.visible(element)) return  

    $(element.offsetParent);
    while ((element = element.parentNode) && element !== document.body) {
        if (Element.getStyle(element, 'position') !== 'static') {
            return isHtml(element) ? $(document.body) : $(element);
        }
    }
    return $(document.body);
};

Element.addMethods({
    getOffsetParent: getOffsetParent
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Geek Num's answer got me in the right direction. I had to add the 4 functions to make it work.

```
function isBody(element) {
    return element.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'BODY';
}

function isHtml(element) {
    return element.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'HTML';
}

function isDocument(element) {
    return element.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE;
}

function isDetached(element) {
    return element !== document.body && !Element.descendantOf(element, document.body);
}

var getOffsetParent = function (element) {
element = $(element);
if (isDocument(element) || isDetached(element) || isBody(element) || isHtml(element))
    return $(document.body);
var isInline = (Element.getStyle(element, 'display') === 'inline');
if (!isInline && element.offsetParent && Element.visible(element)) return $(element.offsetParent);
while ((element = element.parentNode) && element !== document.body) {
    if (Element.getStyle(element, 'position') !== 'static') {
        return isHtml(element) ? $(document.body) : $(element);
    }
}
return $(document.body);
};

Element.addMethods({
    getOffsetParent: getOffsetParent
});
```